# Replicate only documents where {'public':true} in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have the following network/mongodb setup:

- 1 primary mongodb database (`10.0.0.1`, not accessible from the
  Internet) - contains private info in collection A, and a collection
  B, with documents created by a trusted user. At any point in time, a
  user can mark any document in collection B as 'public', which changes
  its property from `{'public':false}` to `{'public':true}`.
- 1 public mongodb database (`10.0.0.2`, runs a webserver accessible from
  the Internet via a reverse proxy) - does not contain collection A,
  but should contain all documents marked as 'public' from collection
  B. This machine will serve those public documents to users outside
  the network.

How would I set up mongodb so that when a document in the primary database (`10.0.0.1`) is updated with `{'public':true}`, it gets replicated to the public mongodb database (`10.0.0.2`)?

**Other details:**

- I'm using the PHP driver
- The documents are small, max 2KB
- The load on these servers will probably never exceed 10 concurrent users
- Eventual consistency is ok, up to a few minutes, but I'd like to know what my options are.

---

So, just to reiterate, here's a use case:

> John VPNs into our private network, opens `http://10.0.0.1/`, creates a
>   document (call it `D2`), marks it as private. John then views an older
>   document, `D1`, and decides to make it public, by clicking the 'Make
>   public' button. The server automagically makes the document available
>   on the public server `example.com` (public IP `x.y.z.w`, internal IP
>   `10.0.0.2`).
>
> John sends an e-mail to Sarah and asks her to read document D1 (the
>   one that was made public). Sarah goes to `http://example.com` and is
>   able to read `D1`, but never sees `D2`.

My goal is to achieve this without having to manually write scripts to synchronize those two databases. I suspect it should be possible, but I can't figure it out from what I've read about MongoDB replication.

I welcome any advice.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't filter what gets replicated via the standard replica set configurations. That would be neat, though.

Comment: I have just found the cloneCollection() command. It looks promising, for a pull style cron job, and it also accepts a query filter.

Comment: Yeah, the trouble with cloneCollection() is it would copy everything every time, rather than doing differential updates. I guess, depending on your data size, that might be fine.

Comment: That's one of the things I'm concerned about too. I'm thinking I can use the 'query' field to filter on a '_timestamp' property, which would result in cloning only those documents in the primary repository that have a _timestamp greater than max(_timestamp) in the public repository. This should result in some sort of incremental cloning. Currently, I'm wondering if there are concurrency issues involved in this scenario.

Comment: The first thing it does when you do cloneCollection is remove the target collection, so I don't think it will work for incremental cloning. You could do the same thing with a simple for loop script, and maybe mark the fields you've already copied over with a flag of some sort.

Comment: I guess at this point, I might as well just write the script that sync's the collections. Too bad that CouchDB has filtered replication and MongoDB doesn't. Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB (as at 2.0.6) does not have support for filtered replication.

However ... it may be possible for you to implement your own scheme to update records based on a [tailable cursor](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors) of MongoDB's [oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#oplog). The local `oplog.rs` capped collection is the same mechanism used to relay changes to members of a replica set and includes details for inserts, deletes, and updates.

For an example of this technique, see this blog post: [Creating Triggers for MongoDB](http://danielweberonline.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/creating-triggers-for-mongodb/).

In your case the actions would be something like:

- copy record from collection A to B if it is inserted or updated with `public:true`
- remove record from collection B if it is deleted or updated in collection A with `public:false`